# Should pointers to "raw" resources be zeroed in destructors?

Tags: c++, destructor, raii

When I wrap "raw" resources in a C++ class, in destructor code I usually simply release the allocated resource(s), without paying attention to additional steps like zeroing out pointers, etc.
e.g.:

```
class File
{
public:
  ...

  ~File()
  {
    if (m_file != NULL)
      fclose(m_file);
  }

private:
  FILE * m_file;
};
```

I wonder if this code style contains a *potential bug*: i.e. **is it possible that a destructor is called more than once?** In this case, the right thing to do in the destructor would be to clear pointers to avoid double/multiple destructions:

```
~File()
{
  if (m_file != NULL)
  {
    fclose(m_file);
    m_file = NULL; // avoid double destruction
  }
}
```

A similar example could be made for heap-allocated memory: if `m_ptr` is a pointer to memory allocated with `new[]`, is the following destructor code OK?

```
// In destructor:
delete [] m_ptr;
```

or should the pointer be cleared, too, to avoid double destruction?

```
// In destructor:
delete [] m_ptr;
m_ptr = NULL; // avoid double destruction
```

Comment: The part of the question about setting the members to `NULL`, has been [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060006/is-it-worth-setting-pointers-to-null-in-a-destructor) [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236736/do-i-need-to-nullify-a-member-variable-in-the-destructor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It is useful if you have a `Close()` function or the like:

```
void Close()
{
    if (m_file != NULL)
    {
        fclose(m_file);
        m_file = NULL;
    }
}
~File()
{
    Close();
}
```

This way, the `Close()` function is idempotent (you can call it as many times as you want), and you avoid one extra test in the destructor.

But since destructors in C++ can only be called once, assigning NULL to pointers there is pointless.

Unless, of course, for debuggin-purposes, particularly if you suspect a double-delete.

Comment: Sure for the Close() method (I use the same pattern in case there is a Close() method).

Comment: +1 Note an important detail: if in your application it does not make sense to `close()` before the object is destroyed (i.e. the lifetime of the object and the resource are the same), then `close()` should not be implemented (it allows for different lifetimes) and the handler should not be reset in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If a destructor is called more than once, you already have undefined behavior. This will also not affect clients that may have a pointer to the resource themselves, so this is not preventing a double delete. A `unique_ptr` or `scoped_ptr` seem to be better solutions to me.

Comment: I'm assuming the resource pointer is local to the class (no resource sharing).

Answer (score 2):

In a buggy application (for example, improper use of std::unique_ptr<> can result in two std::unique_ptr<> holding the same raw pointer), you can end up with a double delete, as the second one goes out of scope.

We care about these **bad cases** - otherwise, what's the point of discussing setting a pointer to `nullptr` in the destructor?  It's going away anyways!

Hence, in this example, at least, it would be better to let the program seg-fault inside a debugger during a unit-test, **so you can trace the real cause of the problem**.

So, in general, I don't find setting pointers to `nullptr` to be particularly useful for memory management.

*You could do it, but a more robust alternative is to **do unit tests** and to judiciously use a **memory checker** like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).*

After all, with some memory errors, your program can seemingly run ok many times, until it crashes unexpectedly - much safer to do quality assurance with a memory checker, especially as your program gets larger, and *memory errors become less obvious*.

Comment: I always NULL out pointers so that if I mess up and reference an object after it's destroyed, I am more likely to get a segfault than silent failure.  Interesting that we do opposite things for exactly the same reasons.

Comment: And there are a lot of cases where valgrind is not an option.