# How to safely zero std::array?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to **safely** zero a `std::array` in a class destructor. From *safely*, I mean I want to be sure that compiler never optimize this zeroing. Here is what I came with:

```
template<size_t SZ>
struct Buf {
    ~Buf() {
        auto ptr = static_cast<volatile uint8_t*>(buf_.data());
        std::fill(ptr, ptr + buf_.size(), 0);
    }

    std::array<uint8_t, SZ> buf_{};
};
```

is this code working as expected? Will that `volatile` keyword prevent optimizing by compiler in any case?

Comment: why do you want that

Comment: @Raildex There are a lot of reasons, but most important thing is security. Assume buf is a cryptography key. You want to zero memory when object destructs to make sure no one can steal key from memory.

Comment: To securely erase memory you need to use some platform/compiler-specific function specifically meant for that purpose. Standard C++ cannot guarantee it. Which platform/compiler are you interested in?

Comment: Related: [Should Member Data be Cleared/Zeroed in the Destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28398666/11082165), [Are passwords stored in memory safe?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29019), and [What kinds of optimizations does 'volatile' prevent in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3604569/11082165)

Comment: @user17732522 I was wondering if I can find a standard-compliant cross-platform method in C++. I know some methods in Windows API to do so, but I was wondering if I can do anything with C++ itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How-to write a password-safe class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785582/how-to-write-a-password-safe-class)

Comment: Short answer, there isn't. Long answer, if you're responsible for security, you should probably need to take some lectures on it.

Comment: I think the C++ Standard does *not* guarantee this. And practically, if you do make sure to zero out some RAM, it's still possible the OS left a copy in swap storage.

Comment: @Afshin then i am just doing a snapshot right before the object gets destroyed :)

Comment: @Suma it seems the idea behind that code is that after casting to `volatile`, compiler cannot optimize zeroing memory too. I guess that's the way then.

Comment: @Afshin `Will that volatile keyword prevent optimizing by compiler in any case?` Did it work when you tried it out?

Comment: @eerorika in my test it did. but a test does not mean *any case*...

Comment: @Afshin You should mention that in the question.

Comment: @aschepler I don't think there will be any way to make sure swap is clean too, even with OS specific APIs. I think if there will be a way to make sure an allocated data does not into swap and stays in RAM (and I don't know if it is possible), safely zeroing RAM will be enough.

Comment: The volatile cast makes sure that the machine will actually perform the write operations and zero out memory. Whether or not it will provide any security is anyone's guess because your threat is not explicitly stated, but my guess is firmy on the "no" side.

Comment: [this is the implementation in crypto++](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/47a6d46db7cbc436d1cc32e64a0f59e613030dec/misc.h#L1373)

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks, since crypto++ is also using this way, I guess we can say it is somehow secure enough in some cases.

Comment: Linux has `mlock` which could help reduce risk. No guarantees, since I'm no expert on the topic and the risk isn't really defined.

Comment: @Afshin: As of Linux-5.14 there is the `memfd_secret` syscall to allocate memory that can't be paged and also is inaccessible to the kernel. And for all intents and purposes, memory that has been locked using `mlock` or `VirtualLock` will also not see its contents paged out to swap memory (albeit there's no strict guaranteed for that). Also the x86_64 red zone is pretty much safe from being paged out.

Comment: If it works now, keep it and write a unit test for it (but in a smart way - not thru a pointer, to not spook the optimizer, but by scanning the entire heap for the specific pattern)

Comment: Windows has SecureZeroMemory

Comment: @datenwolf I know about `VirtualLock` and `SecureZeroMemory`, but I didn't know about `mlock` or `memfd_secret` in linux. I guess I write a small small for class for this. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard itself doesn't make explicit guarantees. It says:

> [dcl.type.cv]
>
> The semantics of an access through a volatile glvalue are implementation-defined. ...
>
> [Note 5: volatile is a hint to the implementation to avoid aggressive optimization involving the object because the value of the object might be changed by means undetectable by an implementation.
> Furthermore, for some implementations, volatile might indicate that special hardware instructions are required to access the object.
> See [intro.execution] for detailed semantics.
> In general, the semantics of volatile are intended to be the same in C++ as they are in C.
> — end note]

Despite the lack of guarantees by the C++ standard, over-writing the memory through a pointer to volatile is one way that some crypto libraries clear memory - at least as a fallback when system specific function isn't available.

P.S. I recommend using `const_cast` instead, in order to avoid accidentally casting to a different type rather than differently qualified same type:

```
auto ptr = const_cast<volatile std::uint8_t*>(buf_.data());
```

Implicit conversion also works:

```
volatile std::uint8_t* ptr = buf_.data();
```

---

System specific functions for this purpose are `SecureZeroMemory` in windows and `explicit_bzero` in some BSDs and glibc.

The C11 standard has an optional function `memset_s` for this purpose and it may be available for you in C++ too but isn't of course guaranteed to be available.

There is a proposal [P1315](http://wg21.link/P1315) to introduce similar function to the C++ standard.

---

Note that secure erasure is not the only consideration that has to be taken to minimise possibility of leaking sensitive data. For example, operating system may swap the memory onto permanent storage unless instructed to not do so. There's no standard way to make such instruction in C++. There's `mlock` in POSIX and `VirtualLock` in windows.

Comment: `memset_s` doesn't appear to guarantee anything related to this.

Comment: @aschepler Why would you not consider `Unlike memset, any call to the memset_s function shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine as described in (5.1.2.3). That is, any call to the memset_s function shall assume that the memory indicated by s and n may be accessible in the future and thus must contain the values indicated by c.` to be a guarantee related to this?

Comment: @eerorika it is funny that cppref states that one option is `std::fill` with volatile pointers in notes here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset

Comment: Oops, I looked at just the function description in https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset which doesn't make it clear. The strict evaluation is explained later under Notes.